# My prime number function is broken but I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, web

The following is a small function that I made that is supposed to list all of the prime numbers between 1 and 1001. It uses a for loop to get a number, then another for loop to check if it is prime. Once it is done checking (if it is prime), it pushes the number to an array. This array should be outputted at the end, but it is not. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

function pNumList(){
    var primeNumbers = [];

    for(var noomber = 2; noomber<=1001; noomber++){
        for(var i = 2; i<noomber; i++){
            if(noomber%i==0){}else{


                primeNumbers.push(noomber);
            }
        }
    }
    pNumbersList.innerHTML = primeNumbers;
}

</script>

<p id="pNumbersList"></p>
<button  onclick="pNumList()" value = "Let's see em">Prime numbers list!</button>
<br>
<p>This might take a sec...</p>

</body>
</html>.
```

Comment: What error is occurring?

Comment: You need to convert array to string like with join `pNumbersList.innerHTML = primeNumbers.join(', ');`

Comment: I just realized that the actual algorithm is what's broken. So, can somebody please explain how to fix the algorithm?

Comment: Your logic to find prime no is not correct at all.

Comment: Your algorithm is incorrect. Your code considers a number to be prime if it's not divisible by any single smaller number. Thus, you'd consider 8 to be prime because it's not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
function pNumList(){
    var primeNumbers = [];

    for(var noomber = 2; noomber<=1001; noomber++){
        var prime = true;
        for(var i = 2; i<noomber; i++){
            if(noomber%i==0){
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            primeNumbers.push(noomber);
        }
    }
    pNumbersList.innerHTML = primeNumbers.join(',');
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctz2o0yo/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function pNumList(){
var primeNumbers = [];

for(var noomber = 2; noomber<=1001; noomber++){
    for(var i = 2; i<noomber; i++){
        if(noomber%i==0){}else{


            primeNumbers.push(noomber);
        }
    }
}
pNumbersList.innerHTML = primeNumbers.toString();
```

You just need to convert your js array to string using toString;
But your algorythm stil incorrect, u add number to array each time when    noomber%i!=0

Answer (score -1):

Here is the right function:

```
function pNumList(){
var primeNumbers = [];

for(var noomber = 2; noomber<=1001; noomber++){
    for(var i = 2; i<noomber; i++){
        if(noomber%i==0){
        break;
        }else{


            primeNumbers.push(noomber);
break;
        }
    }
}
pNumbersList.innerHTML = primeNumbers;

}
```

Comment: Notice the break statements in if and else.